# Why wont Cygnus keep running?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Following the instructions on this [link](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus#section2.1) I only changed 2 config files.

The **first** one is cygnus_instance_1.conf (actually I just renamed the example file):

```
#####
#
# Configuration file for apache-flume
#
#####
# Copyright 2014 Telefonica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
# 
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

# Who to run cygnus as. Note that you may need to use root if you want
# to run cygnus in a privileged port (<1024)
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus

# Where is the config folder
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

# Which is the config file
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent.conf

# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Flume parameters 
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent

# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus. It is important to put the extension '.log' in order to the log rotation works properly
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081

# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

And the **second** config is agent_1.conf (where I removed all but the mysql DB because that is the one I am using):

```
# Copyright 2014 Telefónica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
# 
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/agent.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mysql-sink
cygnusagent.channels = mysql-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = Trace_Data
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = Sensor
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMySQLSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_grouping = false
# the FQDN/IP address where the MySQL server runs
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = 127.0.0.1
# the port where the MySQL server listes for incomming connections
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
# a valid user in the MySQL server
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = root
# password for the user above
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = klasika
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column
# select the table type from table-by-destination and table-by-service-path
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.table_type = table-by-destination
# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_size = 100
# timeout for batch accumulation
cygunsagent.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_timeout = 30

#=============================================
# mysql-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

#============================================
```

I even did the test successfully and got the following output:

```
Tests run: 72, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:28.380s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 08 15:25:16 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The test worked because I properly configured java and maven:

```
[root@localhost fiware-cygnus]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65
[root@localhost fiware-cygnus]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
[root@localhost fiware-cygnus]# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

So all good when I hit `service cygnus start` because I get:

```
Starting Cygnus 1...                                       [  OK  ]
```

But then 2 seconds later when I hit `service cygnus status` I get:

```
cygnus-flume-ng dead but pid file exists
```

Context broker is working perfectly by the way, but it just doesnt know that the subscriptions Im entering are not going anywere...

This is the log from cygnus (there is no timestamp so I ill post the first and the last one):

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplic$
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.10.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/cygnus.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at org.apache.flume.node.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:58)


Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplic$
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.10.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/cygnus.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at org.apache.flume.node.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:58)
```

**I demonstrated that I have the latest version of java running and that its home env is set. What am I doing wrong here?** I should stress that I havent touched any other config files what so ever. Here is the full list that I found:

```
[root@localhost conf]# ls
agent_1.conf         cygnus_instance_1.conf         flume-env.sh.template  grouping_rules.conf.template  krb5_login.conf   log4j.properties.template
agent.conf.template  cygnus_instance.conf.template  grouping_rules.conf    krb5.conf.template            log4j.properties  README.md
```

---

**EDIT1:** log4.properties as requested:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties.
#
# For testing, it may also be convenient to specify
# -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console when launching flume.

#flume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
flume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE
flume.log.dir=./logs
flume.log.file=flume.log

log4j.logger.org.apache.flume.lifecycle = INFO
log4j.logger.org.jboss = WARN
log4j.logger.org.mortbay = INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver = WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = INFO

# Define the root logger to the system property "flume.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${flume.root.logger}


# Stock log4j rolling file appender
# Default log rotation configuration
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] (%C.%M:%L) %x - %m%n


# Warning: If you enable the following appender it will fill up your disk if you don't have a cleanup job!
# This uses the updated rolling file appender from log4j-extras that supports a reliable time-based rolling policy.
# See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html
# Add "DAILY" to flume.root.logger above if you want to use this
log4j.appender.DAILY=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] (%C.%M:%L) %x - %m%n


# console
# Add "console" to flume.root.logger above if you want to use this
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d (%t) [%p - %l] %m%n
```

**EDIT2** Here is the result of the ls -l command:

```
[root@localhost conf]# ls -l
total 64
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root   root    5289 Nov 30 12:23 agent_1.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus 14481 Nov  5 15:45 agent.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root   root    1732 Nov 30 09:29 cygnus_instance_1.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus  1732 Nov  5 15:45 cygnus_instance.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus  1197 Nov  5 15:45 flume-env.sh.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root   root    3597 Dec  7 12:15 grouping_rules.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus  3597 Nov  5 15:45 grouping_rules.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus   325 Nov  5 15:45 krb5.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus   135 Nov  5 15:45 krb5_login.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus  3063 Nov  5 15:45 log4j.properties
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus  3659 Nov  5 15:45 log4j.properties.template
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 cygnus cygnus  2195 Nov  5 15:45 README.md
```

**EDIT 2.1** Here is the ownership of var/log/cygnus:

```
[root@localhost conf]# ls -l /var/log/cygnus
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cygnus cygnus 14152 Dec  9 14:37 cygnus.log
```

**EDIT 3** My newest log:

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplic$
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.10.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
11 Dec 2015 11:16:13,101 ERROR [main] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main:250)  - A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows. Details=The specified configuration file does not exist: /usr/cygnus/conf/agent.conf
```

***If you are not familiar with FIWARE technologies, please ignore this question!***

Comment: Can you show the content of `conf/log4j.properties`, please?

Comment: @frb I added as requested. I should stress that I haven't touched that file and left it at default because it wasn't specified otherwise in the installation process...

Comment: I should not be modified... but there is something wrong with the log file. Which are the permissions of all the files within `conf\`? And which are the permissions of `/var/log/cygnus`?

Comment: @frb Hi, check out my last edit2 where I did ls -l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is realted to the logs writting. By default, the logs are written in the path specified at `conf/log4j.properties`, i.e. `./logs/flume.log`. Nevertheless, such a path should be overwritten by the configuration put at `conf/cygnys_instance_1.conf`, i.e. `/var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log`. I still do not know why (possibly there is a bug), but your Cygnus is overwritting the log file name (`cygnus.log`) but not the path (`./log`). The result is Cygnus tries to write in `./log/cygnus.log`, and I guess `.` is a path only allowed for writting to the `root` user (Cygnus runs as `cygnus` user). The workaround is to edit `log4j.properties` and configure:

```
flume.log.dir=/var/log/cygnus
```

Comment: I edited my question that includes my newest log. Please check it out, as your solution still hasnt fixed my problem. Cygnus now dies after 5 sec...

Comment: Ok I figured this one out, I just renamed agent_1.conf into agent.conf and it is running. My question now is should I also rename cygnus_instance_1.conf into cygnus_instance.conf?

Comment: You should not. An id (`1`, in your case), is required both in `agent_<id>.conf` and `cygnus_instance_<id>.conf`. That's the way several configurations of Cygnus are run at the same time (just to inform you, I think this is not a feature you may need).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fixed it by changing the config-file in the `cygnus_instance_<id>.conf`:

```
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_<id>.conf
```