# Why wont Cygnus receive a subscription on my CentOS 6.7?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I just finished testing the entire thing on my virtual machine environment and now I am trying to launch it on the dedicated server. And now I ran into a completely new issue. First I confirmed that I have both context Broker and centos running (on 1026 and 5050 respectively):

```
[root@centos conf]# netstat -ntlpd
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1026                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1321/contextBroker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1282/mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1791/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1260/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::1026                     :::*                        LISTEN      1321/contextBroker
tcp        0      0 :::8081                     :::*                        LISTEN      2481/java
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1260/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::5050                     :::*                        LISTEN      2481/java
[root@centos conf]# service cygnus status
Cygnus 1 status...
cygnus-flume-ng (pid  2481) is running...
```

Then I confirmed that I have data on contextBroker because this command gave me an appropriate response:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1"
        }
    ]
} 
EOF
```

Following the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180456/why-wont-cygnus-keep-running/34220810?noredirect=1#comment56188828_34220810) to an issue with root user and logging I fixed the log4j.properties and changed the follwing:

```
flume.log.dir=/var/log/cygnus
```

I then started cygnus and got the following log:

```
Starting an ordered shutdown of Cygnus
Stopping sources
Stopping http-source (lyfecycle state=START)
All the channels are empty
Stopping channels
Stopping mysql-channel (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping sinks
Stopping mysql-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /usr/cygnus/conf/flume-env.sh
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplic$
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.11.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,684 INFO  [main] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main:235)  - Starting a Jetty server listening on port 8081 (Management Interface)
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,700 INFO  [main] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,700 INFO  [main] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main:238)  - Starting Cygnus application
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,700 INFO  [Thread-1] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - jetty-6.1.26
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,713 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start:61)  - Configuration provider starting
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,715 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:133)  - Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,725 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty:1016)  - Processing:mysql-sink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,725 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty:1016)  - Processing:mysql-sink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,725 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty:1016)  - Processing:mysql-sink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,755 INFO  [Thread-1] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,764 WARN  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid:319)  - Agent configuration for 'cygunsagent' does not contain any channels. Marking it as invalid.
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,765 WARN  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration:127)  - Agent configuration invalid for agent 'cygunsagent'. It will be removed.
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,766 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration:140)  - Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [cygnusagent]
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,766 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels:150)  - Creating channels
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,778 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory.create:40)  - Creating instance of channel mysql-channel type memory
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,782 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels:205)  - Created channel mysql-channel
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,783 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create:39)  - Creating instance of source http-source, type org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,791 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.<init>:75)  - Cygnus version (0.11.0.2a9c87fb7fd6156225e2eed7fbc9792f1d9c5dfe)
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,807 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.configure:141)  - Startup completed
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,826 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create:40)  - Creating instance of sink: mysql-sink, type: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,839 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration:119)  - Channel mysql-channel connected to [http-source, mysql-sink]
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,843 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:138)  - Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTT$
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,844 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:145)  - Starting Channel mysql-channel
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,910 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register:110)  - Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel, registered successfully.
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,910 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start:94)  - Component type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel started
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,911 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:173)  - Starting Sink mysql-sink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,913 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-1] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink.start:153)  - [mysql-sink] Startup completed
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,915 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:184)  - Starting Source http-source
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,916 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize:92)  - Grouping rules read:
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,916 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents:101)  - Shutting down configuration: { sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HT$
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,917 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents:105)  - Stopping Source http-source
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,920 ERROR [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.parseGroupingRules:165)  - Error while parsing the Json-based grouping rules file. Details=null
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,921 WARN  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize:98)  - Grouping rules syntax has errors
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,948 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - jetty-6.1.26
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,973 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,974 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register:110)  - Monitoried counter group for type: SOURCE, name: http-source, registered successfully.
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,974 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-2] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start:94)  - Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source started
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,974 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.unsupervise:171)  - Stopping component: EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state$
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,974 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - Stopped SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,975 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:139)  - Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source stopped
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,976 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:145)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. source.start.time == 1450355737974
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,976 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:151)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. source.stop.time == 1450355737975
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,976 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append-batch.accepted == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,976 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append-batch.received == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,976 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append.accepted == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,976 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append.received == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,977 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.events.accepted == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,977 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.events.received == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,977 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.open-connection.count == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,977 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.stop:172)  - Http source http-source stopped. Metrics: SOURCE:http-source{src.events.accepted=0, src.open-connection.count=0, src.append.receiv$
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,977 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents:115)  - Stopping Sink mysql-sink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,977 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.unsupervise:171)  - Stopping component: SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@76da521f counterGroup:{ name:nul$
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,987 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents:125)  - Stopping Channel mysql-channel
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,987 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.unsupervise:171)  - Stopping component: org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: mysql-channel}
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,987 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:139)  - Component type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel stopped
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,987 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:145)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.start.time == 1450355737910
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,988 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:151)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.stop.time == 1450355737987
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,988 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.capacity == 1000
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,988 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.current.size == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,988 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.event.put.attempt == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,988 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.event.put.success == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,988 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.event.take.attempt == 1
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,989 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop:167)  - Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel. channel.event.take.success == 0
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,989 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:138)  - Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTT$
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,989 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:145)  - Starting Channel mysql-channel
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,989 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-3] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start:94)  - Component type: CHANNEL, name: mysql-channel started
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,992 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:173)  - Starting Sink mysql-sink
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,993 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink.start:153)  - [mysql-sink] Startup completed
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,993 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents:184)  - Starting Source http-source
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,993 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-4] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize:92)  - Grouping rules read:
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,994 ERROR [lifecycleSupervisor-1-4] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.parseGroupingRules:165)  - Error while parsing the Json-based grouping rules file. Details=null
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,994 WARN  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-4] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize:98)  - Grouping rules syntax has errors
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,994 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-4] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - jetty-6.1.26
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,996 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-4] (org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info:67)  - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
17 Dec 2015 13:35:37,996 INFO  [lifecycleSupervisor-1-4] (org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start:94)  - Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source started
```

Then I tried to subscribe the previously mentioned data to cygnus:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "pressure"
        "temperature"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "pressure",
                "temperature"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

Even after I updated the information on context Broker thinking it would trigger an event:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "temperature",
                    "type": "float",
                    "value": "333"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pressure",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "value": "555"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
} 
EOF
```

But the cygnus log remainged exactly the same and its like nothing even got through to it. Which is odd considering my agent_1.conf:

```
# Copyright 2014 Telefónica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
#
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
#
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
#
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/agent.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mysql-sink
cygnusagent.channels = mysql-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = Trace_Data
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = Sensor
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMySQLSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_grouping = false
# the FQDN/IP address where the MySQL server runs
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = 127.0.0.1
# the port where the MySQL server listes for incomming connections
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
# a valid user in the MySQL server
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = root
# password for the user above
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = klasika
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column
# select the table type from table-by-destination and table-by-service-path
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.table_type = table-by-destination
# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_size = 1
# timeout for batch accumulation
cygunsagent.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_timeout = 30

#=============================================
# mysql-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

#============================================
```

It has 5050 and notify as the reference address. I double checked the cygnus_instance_1.conf as well and it is pointing at agent_1.conf

```
#####
#
# Configuration file for apache-flume
#
#####
# Copyright 2014 Telefonica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
#
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
#
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
#
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

# Who to run cygnus as. Note that you may need to use root if you want
# to run cygnus in a privileged port (<1024)
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus

# Where is the config folder
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

# Which is the config file
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf

# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Flume parameters
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent

# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus. It is important to put the extension '.log' in order to the log rotation works properly
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081

# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

This is the content of my config folder in /usr/cygnus/conf:

```
[root@centos conf]# ls
agent_1.conf         cygnus_instance_1.conf         flume-env.sh           grouping_rules.conf           krb5.conf           krb5_login.conf   log4j.properties.template
agent.conf.template  cygnus_instance.conf.template  flume-env.sh.template  grouping_rules.conf.template  krb5.conf.template  log4j.properties  README.md
```

I noticed that there is an exacted mirror of this in /etc/cygnus/conf but I didn't touch anything because the installation only intructs me to use the /usr/ folder.

Here is my Mysql create statement. In this table I am expecting to receive the context broker data but I get nothing of course since the log didnt register anything.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_room1_room (
sensorID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
recvTime mediumtext, 
fiwareservicepath text, 
entityId text, 
entityType text, 
pressure text, 
pressure_md text, 
temperature text, 
temperature_md text,
PRIMARY KEY (sensorID));
```

**Edit 1**:

Here is the listener

[root@centos conf]# nc -l 5050

But when I tried subscribing or updating context, nothing was received on the listener side. I am not taking into account the client side of nc: `nc 127.0.0.1 5050` because it successfully sends everything i type (even gibberish).

I also tried the test: `/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console`. I tried both 5050 and 8081 ports to subscribe to and then update context but nothing is read on the console.

Comment: Could you temporarly shut down Cygnus process and run a dummy listener in that port (e.g. `nc -l -p 5050`) and send new updates to Orion in order to check if something is received, please? Edit your question post to add your findings.

Comment: @Vrankela, since the Orion update seems to be working, we only have two options: Cygnus is not really listening, or the communication between Orion and Cygnus is blocked (iptables, a firewall, something like that). Could you test one of the testing scripts for Cygnus? This one emulates a simple notification: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/resources/ngsi-examples/notification-json-simple.sh . If Cygnus logs the reception of the emulated notification, then Cygnus is OK and the problem is the communication between Orion and Cygnus.

Comment: @frb I created a file called cygnusTest.sh and put the contents of the link into it and did the following

`[root@centos cygnus]# sh cygnusTest.sh 127.0.0.1:5050`

The command gave me the follwong output:

`* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5050 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5050 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5050
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> User-Agent: orion/0.10.0
> Fiware-Service: def_serv
> Fiware-ServicePath: def_serv_path
> Content-Length: 460`

And basically printed out the contents...

Comment: The script must be run as `sh cygnusTest.sh http://localhost:5050/notify <choose_a_service> <choose_a_servicePath>`

Comment: @frb Look:

`[root@centos cygnus]# sh cygnusTest.sh http://localhost:5050/notify cygnus /usr/cygnus/conf/
* About to connect() to localhost port 5050 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5050 (#0)
> POST /notify HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5050
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> User-Agent: orion/0.10.0
> Fiware-Service: cygnus
> Fiware-ServicePath: /usr/cygnus/conf/
> Content-Length: 460
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0`

Comment: I'm not sure about "Edit 1", but I would said that the right syntax to run nc in listener mode uses `-p` just before the port number, i.e. `nc -l -p 5050` (not `nc -l 5050`). Is there a typo in the "Edit 1" text?

Comment: In addition, you could check if Orion is sending notifications looking to the logs. I could elaborate on the details, but first I'd need to know which Orion version are you using (`curl <host:port>:1026/version` would give that information). Could you add that information editing your question post, please?

Comment: As you can see in the output of the script, a `200 OK` response is received, i.e. a `200 OK` has been sent by Cygnus. Thus, Cygnus is running properly and it is waiting for Orion's notifications. The problem can only be in Orion or in the communication between Orion and Cygnus.

Comment: @fgalan It works just fine without the -p. The orion version is 0.26.1.

Frb, is there something wrong with my subscribe context?

Comment: You can check if Orion 0.26.1 is sending notifications (and if the result of this operation is success or failure) running it with `-logLevel INFO`. Then, when a new update is processed, the following is printed in the logs: 1) a message with the following pattern `Notification Successfully Sent to <URL>`, 2) a message with the following pattern `Notification failure for <ip:port> (<error description)`, 3) none of them.

Comment: This is the meaning of the above messages is: 1) notification was sucessuflly sent, 2) Orion tries to send notification but a failure occurs, 2) Orion didn't attemp to send notification (typically because no subscription was triggered by the update). Which situation is the one you have?

Comment: @fgalan Can you elaborate where I should put the  -logLevel command? I tried to put it inside the header of the curl command but i received:

`-bash: -logLevel: command not found`

Comment: `-logLevel` is a CLI parameter of the contextBroker process, so you have to set it at contextBroker starting time either directly (see http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/cli/index.html) or as part of BROKER_EXTRA_OPS if you running contextBroker as system service (see http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/running/index.html).

Comment: so what you are saying that I should do: `contextbroker start -logLevel INFO' after I stopped context broker?

Because I did just that and I see no printing of the mentioned scenarios in the console.

Comment: Not really... you should edit /etc/syconfig/contextBroker file, ensure BROKER_EXTRA_OPS is uncomented and add `-logLevel INFO` to that parameter (something like `BROKER_EXTRA_OPS="... -logLevel INFO"`). Then, restart Orion with `sudo /etc/init.d/contextBroker restart`. More information at http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/running/index.html

Comment: @fgalan I have no idea what just happened but I successfully turned on the log and it started working...

I've made so many subscriptions now, I think I may have made a clutter out of it. Is there any way I can check for active subscriptions so that I can terminate and clean them all?

Comment: Yes, there are. Have a look to the following Q&A posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354921/cancel-subscription-on-cygnus and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399054/subscription-to-cb-working-but-not-visible. Don't forget to give your +1 if you find them useful, so other users may know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I seriously have no idea why that subscription didn't work, but thanks to @fgalan I did manage to read the logs so I am posting the subscription that did trigger the event to cygnus:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "temperature"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "pressure"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT5S"
}
EOF
```

Thank you @fgalan one more time!