# Cancel Subscription on Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have a subscription made to an entity's attribute to a MySql sink. The problem is that while I was testing my rest service to do a subscription if the data was not yet persisted, i made a ton of subscriptions. Now every time I do an update on the entity's attribute what happens is that the value is persisted a lot of times. Is there anyway of deleting a subscription without the subscriptionID?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. First, you can list the existing subscriptions with the `GET /v2/subscriptions` operation (have a look to the [draft NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/)).

Once you have the IDs the unsubscribeContext operation:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/unsubscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "subscriptionId": "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8"
}
EOF
```

I recommend to have a look to [Orion context broker documenation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/0.26.0/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#context-subscriptions).

Comment: Even so, it repeats itself over and over again. I deleted all subscriptions. And when i create new ones a can't see them with the command http:/localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions

Comment: Which Orion version are you using? Which kind of subscription do you have (ONTIMEINTERVAL or ONCHANGE)?

Comment: I have ONCHANGE subscriptions.

Comment: Great! As using ONTIMEINTERVAL is not recomended anymore (they have been deprecated: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/deprecated.md). What about the Orion version you are using, please?

Comment: Yes i noticed that :) i'm using Orion 0.26.0 version

Comment: Just to check if I have understand the problem. Starting in a situation with all subscriptions removed (i.e. no subscriptions at DB, thus the result of `echo 'db.csubs.count()' | mongo orion --quiet` is 0), you create several subscriptions (let's say 5 subscriptions) using `POST /v1/subscribeContext`. Then, you run `GET /v2/subscriptions` and get `[]` as result. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exacly right, I just ran the command echo `'db.csubs.count()' | mongo orion --quiet` and the result is 0 too. Then i ran the `GET /v2/subscriptions` and i get `[] ` as result even though i've made several subscriptions. Even so the values are getting stored in MySql table.

Comment: Given that it seems to be a different issue, I'd suggest to deal with it in a separate post. In that sense, could you create a new question at SOF about it, please? Include in the question post the usual information: 1) Orion version, 2) how Orion runs (i.e, output of the `ps ax | grep contextBroker` command), 3) the exact sequence of steps that from a "reset situation" (no subscriptions in the DB, i.e. `echo `echo 'db.csubs.count()' | mongo orion --quiet` prints 0) reproduce the problems. Please, include the exact subscription operation (URL, headers, payload, etc.) you are using. Thx!

Comment: Regarding point 3) above, it could be also important to include in that new post how much time (aproximately) passes between one step and the following, given that it could be related with csubs cache so timming could be relevant.

Comment: I leave here the link for the the new topic for anyone with the same issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399054/subscription-to-cb-working-but-not-visible